# Distance between users is always 0 even though coordinates are different in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I'm trying to show distance between multiple users who are registered to app and show in a `Listview`, and the code for `Listview`, is below:-

```
class DistanceListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DistanceListViewState createState() => _DistanceListViewState();
}

class _DistanceListViewState extends State<DistanceListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profiles = Provider.of<List<ProfileData>>(context) ?? [];
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: profiles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return DistanceCard(profile: profiles[index], index: index);
        });
  }
}
```

Where `profiles` is a list that contains all the locations of user's locations in it. Right now I've created two dummy users with co-ordinates **35.6762, 139.6503** and **6.9271, 79.8612** .

Code for `DistanceCard` goes as follows:-

```
class DistanceCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final ProfileData profile;
  DistanceCard({this.index, this.profile});
  @override
  _DistanceCardState createState() => _DistanceCardState();
}

class _DistanceCardState extends State<DistanceCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profiles = Provider.of<List<ProfileData>>(context) ?? [];
    final longitude = widget.profile.location.longitude;
    final latitude = widget.profile.location.latitude;
    var distance;

    futureconvert() async {
      distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
          longitude,
          latitude,
          profiles[widget.index].location.longitude,
          profiles[widget.index].location.latitude);
      return distance;
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureconvert(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Card(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               child: Text(distance)),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Here's the problem, when widget gets rendered, `distance` always shows as **0.0**. Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Not a Flutter developer but take a look at the example from the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html . You are not using the value from `snapshot` which should contain the result from your async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first let me point out the **error** you are making.

You are trying to find distance between the same coordinates,

let me explain.

You are passing 2 parameters into distance card.

- Profile[index]
- index

```
return DistanceCard(profile: profiles[index], index: index);
```

okay?

Now in Distance Card, you are using Provider to fetch the exact same profile lat and profile long from the list of profiles here.

```
 distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
          longitude,
          latitude,
          profiles[widget.index].location.longitude,
          profiles[widget.index].location.latitude);
      return distance;
    }
```

What is "latitude" here ? -> profile[index].location.latitude

and the other point ? -> profiles[widget.index].location.latitude

Since the index is same, you are fetching the exact same object hence **0.0** is the distance.

I would recommend to make one single "**anchor**" coordinate which is fixed, like the current location of the user, or location of any one user and then find the relative locations.

Let me know if this fixed your error.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically using the same object twice, so the distance from itself its 0

```
return DistanceCard(profile: profiles[index], index: index)
// You're passing the profile, let's say at index 0 of your list
```

Then in the `_DistanceCardState` (which I recommend you create this code outside of the build method)

```
final profiles = Provider.of<List<ProfileData>>(context) ?? []; //This is the Provider that has the same list you used to build the DistanceCard
final longitude = widget.profile.location.longitude; //The longitude of the profile at index 0
final latitude = widget.profile.location.latitude; //The latitude of the profile at index 0
var distance;

futureconvert() async {
  distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
      longitude,
      latitude,
      profiles[widget.index].location.longitude, //this and longitude refers to the same value (index 0 for the first one)
      profiles[widget.index].location.latitude); //this and latitude refers to the same value (index 0 for the first one)
  return distance;
}
```

And so on when iterating through the list. So the question is do you want to compare it with whom exactly? All the other `Profiles` in the List? The next one in the List?

```
class _DistanceCardState extends State<DistanceCard> {
  List<ProfileData> profiles;
  var distance;

  @override
  didChangeDependencies(){
    super.didchangeDependencies();
    profiles = Provider.of<List<ProfileData>>(context) ?? [];
  }

    futureconvert() async {
      int anotherIndex = 0;
      if(profiles.length != widget.index) anotherIndex = widget.index + 1;
      //This will compare it to the next profile in the list
      distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
          widget.profile.location.longitude,
          widget.profile.location.latitude,
          profiles[anotherIndex].location.longitude, //Give another longitude
          profiles[anotherIndex].location.latitude); //Give another latitude
      return distance;
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureconvert(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Card(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               child: Text(distance)),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```